# Transformation or correspondence between language and real number

Tags: reference-request, computational-complexity, big-picture, computational-number-theory, formal-languages

As we know, formal language can be regarded as a set of strings of alphabet, and real number can be regarded as sequence generated by set of integers, for example, denominators of the simple continued fraction may form a set.

Algorithms analyze language and algorithms decide or output set of integers generating reals. Now, are there any transformation or correspondence between language and real number, which keep the computational complexity in same class? As we know, Godel encoding may be such a kind of transformation. Any reference?

Also, we hope the transformation is bijective.

Comment: You didn't mention computable/definable numbers (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number). Does it relate to your question?

Comment: @LucGuyot it is related. but since a set of integers can be regarded as equivalent to a real, I think it is not necessary to mention it.

Comment: The question seems to be: can we construct a bijection between the set of expressions in a formal language and the set of real numbers? If this is what you are asking, the answer is trivially _no_, because the two sets have different cardinalities (unless you allow uncountable languages, like adding a constant symbol for every real number).

Comment: Maybe you want to use the rationals since infinite sequences of symbols aren't usually considered. Also, the "alphabet" used for reals is infinite.

Comment: @Wojowu no, You have misunderstood what I mean. a real may be regarded as a set of integer, so I just ask whether there is an encoding or map or bijection which transforms a real into a language or a language into a real. In such a way, we may construct  two algorithms  for a language and a real which keep the computational complexity in same class.